# Cloud Firestore REST API. How to create several documents in one request?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

I need to rest api upload a lot of documents to Cloud Firestore. I figured out how to load one document. But it takes a lot of time. I want to send several documents by one request. I just can’t do how it can be done ....

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be possible.  Consider instead [beginning a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/beginTransaction), then [committing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/commit) multiple documents in that transaction.  You're looking at two requests in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also inclined to the fact that this is not possible. But it is very strange.  
If correctly understood, then you offer:  
   1 request. Start the transaction.   
   2 - (n-1) requests. Send the document to the server.   
   n request. Transaction commit.  

Will this give a gain in speed? Compared to the transactionless variant?

Comment: No, if you don't need need the commits to be atomic.